# When GCM service stop date delayed?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have encountered Google's announcement for delay of termination date of GCM service, i knew it was originally 11, April 2019.
When GCM service stop date delayed?

> As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and
>   client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as May 29,
>   2019. Migrate GCM apps to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new
>   features. See the migration guide

Comment: You're question is a bit confusing, but I'll assume that you mean *why* the stop date was delayed. I didn't find any official reason disclosed, but what I can only assume is that the extra time is for the developers who up to until now still haven't migrated.

Comment: Since when? Do you know? I have to explain the date to my clients.

Comment: I don't represent Google and I mentioned that what I stated above was an assumption. If you are looking for something official, I suggest you send a direct email to Google Support.